# req.cookies is woring in postman but not in browser

Tags: reactjs, node.js, express, cookies

```
import express from "express";
import morgan from "morgan";
import userRouter from "./Routes/userRoutes";
import { connectDB } from "./Config/DBConnection";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import cookieParser from "cookie-parser"
import cors from "cors"
const app = express();
dotenv.config();
connectDB();
const port = process.env.PORT;
const whitelist = ['http://localhost:5173']
const corsOptions = {
    credentials: true,
    origin: function (origin, callback) {
        if (whitelist.indexOf(origin) !== -1) {
            callback(null, true)
        } else {
            callback(new Error('Not allowed by CORS'))
        }
    }
}
// app.use(cors(corsOptions));
app.use(cors());

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cookieParser(process.env.COOKIE_PARSER_SECRET))
app.use(morgan('dev'))
app.use("/api/users", userRouter);

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log("Listing on port number ", port);
});
```

This is my server.ts file. I switched between those 2 app.use(cors) while using in postman and browser.

```
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken"
import { userModel } from "../Models/userSchemaModel";

export const verifyToken = async (req, res, next) => {
    const authCookie = req.cookies.token
    const userIDCookie = req.cookies.userID
    if (!authCookie) {
        console.log(authCookie);

        res.status(401).json({ Error: "Auth Token not provided!" })
    } else {
        const user = await userModel.findById(userIDCookie)
        // console.log(user.tokens);
        const isMatchingToken = user?.tokens.find(token => token.accessToken === authCookie)
        console.log(isMatchingToken);

        if (isMatchingToken) {
            jwt.verify(authCookie, process.env.TOKEN_SECRET, (err, data) => {
                if (err) {
                    res.status(403).json({ Error: "Authentication failed!" })
                }
                else if (data) {
                    // console.log(data);
                    req.user = data
                    next()
                }
            })
        } else {
            res.status(403).json({ Error: "Token is not valid!" })
        }
    }
}
```

This is verfyToken.ts file. which is used to verify token... here req.cookies is working while call it from postman but it doesn't provide token while call it from browser.

```
res.cookie('token', accessToken, { maxAge: 2628288 * 1000 })
res.cookie('userID', user._id, { maxAge: 2628288 * 1000 })
```

And this is how I storing my cookies.